# Create a New Project with C/C++ Support

Tags: android, android-studio

Hello guys i want to start project with c/c++ support as shown in the following link

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#new-project

there is 1 points  "In the Configure your new project section of the wizard, check the Include C++ Support checkbox. " which is  shown in following image

[image]

i  cant find that  that check box(Include C++ Support) any where,  can any one help me to find this option or suggest any other way to do it?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html Please Start Reading from top to Bottom Here All are done on this page @Redman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your android studio to the latest version 2.2.1.0 and than try creating new project. There will be a check box for exactly what you want. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Hope this helps you!

Comment: ok thank man , just finished updating and found that option +1 and accepted:)

Comment: I already created a project. Now how can I include the c++ support

Comment: Cant' find in the current dialog.